# Stuck in loop of a multi-menu program

Tags: c

I would like to have two nested menus in my program but it keeps looping both menus, after I entered the option for the second menu. When I remove the first menu, the code is working fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int a, b, c, d, choice1, choice2, i, s[100], swap;
    unsigned long int fact;
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Menu Driven Program\n");
        printf("1. 2D Array\n");
        printf("2. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice1);                  
       
        switch (choice1) 
        { 
        case 1:
            printf("Choose options given below\n");
            printf("1. Addition\n");
            printf("2. Subtraction\n");
            printf("3. Multiplication\n");
            printf("4. Linear search\n");
            printf("5. Bubble sort\n");
            printf("6. Exit\n");
        
            printf("Enter Your Choice\n\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice2);
            break;
    
        switch (choice2)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter any two numbers\n");
            scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

            c = a + b;

            printf("Your answer is %d \n", c);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

the output will be

```sh
Menu Driven Program
1. 2D Array
2. Exit
Enter your choice
1

Choose options given below
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication

Menu Driven Program
1. 2D Array
2. Exit
```

It is stuck in the loop where it goes back to the beginning after I entered the value for the second menu. I would like it to enter the `case` of the second switch so that it runs the addition code.

Comment: Please post the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: The code is missing several }'s, cases in the switch statements and indentation. Please edit and reformat so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, the `switch(choice2)` should be executed after `choice1` was set to `1`. If that is the case, you need to remove the `break` after the `scanf` like so:

```c
while(1) {    
    printf("Menu Driven Program\n");

    printf("1. 2D Array\n");
    printf("2. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice1);                  
   
    switch (choice1) { 
    case 1:
        printf("Choose options given below\n");
        printf("1. Addition\n");
        printf("2. Subtraction\n");
        printf("3. Multiplication\n");
        printf("4. Linear search\n");
        printf("5. Bubble sort\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n");
    
        printf("Enter Your Choice\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice2);

        switch (choice2) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter any two numbers\n");
            scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
            c = a + b;
            printf("Your answer is %d \n", c);
            break;
        }
        break; // Break here important otherwise fall-through to exit()-call
    case 2:
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, good to know. have fun hacking

Comment: wait where do you put printf("2. Exit\n");........i mean where should i put case 2: exit(0);

Comment: put it into the switch for choice1, because it part of the first menu so it must be part of the parent (first) switch, I'll edit the code

Comment: its working in vsc but when i run using windows i didnt get answer of addition it suddenly close

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot the break, will edit